# Possible types in xml/xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Is an xml value by definition a string, or is any interpretation ever done (ignoring xsd types or something such as `xs:element`)? For example:

```
<Values>
    <String>hi</String>
    <Number>2</Number>
</Values>
```

Would both `Values/String` and `Values/Number` produce a string value? If the answer is yes, then wouldn't the only possible values in a xpath be either `string`, `string[]`, `node`, and `node[]`? For example:

- `Values/String` --> string
- `Values` --> node (not a terminal value)
- `Values/*` --> string[]
- `Others/Other` --> node[] (from below)

  ```
  <Others>
      <Other><x>2</x></Other>
      <Other><x>2</x></Other>
  </Others>
  ```

Finally, doing `//x` would give me a list -- `["2", "2"]`. Is it ever possible to get a list-of-list with an xpath, or is that impossible in xml? For example, in json (which supports a list type) I can do the following equivalent to get a list-of-list:

```
{"x": [{"y": [1,2]}, {"y": [3,4]}]}
x[*].y --> [[1,2], [3,4]]
gives an array of terminal value, which is an array here
```

Comment: "Interpolation" - do you mean "Interpretation"?

Comment: @MichaelKay correct, updated.

Comment: Should it be `{"x": [{"y": [1,2]}, {"y": [3,4]}]}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the XDM data model, which is the XPath/XQuery view of XML, the value of an element is always "untyped" (essentially, string) unless you validate the data against an XSD schema.

XDM allows sequences of nodes or atomic values, but not sequences of sequences.

XDM 3.1 supports arrays as well as sequences, and unlike sequences, arrays can be nested. This was introduced mainly to support JSON, and is not used when processing XML.

Comment: thanks for this. Two follow-ups: (1) when you say XDM allows "atomic" values -- what do you mean? Is this the same thing as saying it's always a string? (2) Can you link to the XDM 3.1 part where you could do something like `[[1,2],[3,4]]`? What path could you use to emulate the `x[*].y` path?

Comment: Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments; the SO dialog structure doesn't make it easy to answer them, especially when there is more than one. Also, you're asking about concepts that are explained in detail in the XDM specification, if you're interested in knowing more about it I suggest you start by reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Q: *Is an xml value by definition a string*?
A: Yes. From [Xpath docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#element-nodes)

> The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.

Q: *Is it ever possible to get a list-of-list with an xpath*?
A: Text nodes exists within an element or node so a "list" of values could be the values of elements with the same name and siblings of each other ([see following-sibling, preceding-sibling axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)).

```
<Others>
  <Other>
    <x>2</x>
    <x>2</x>
  </Other>
  <Other>
    <x>2</x>
    <x>2</x>
  </Other>
</Others>
```

`//*[x]` xpath expression would return the 2 "lists" above where `Other` elements can be seen as brackets and `x` elements as element separator or comma.

```
<Other><x>2</x><x>2</x></Other>
   [      2    ,  2        ]
```

Using python to get the list of lists

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> doc = etree.parse('tmp.xml')
>>> [o.xpath('x/text()') for o in doc.xpath('//*[x]')]
[['2', '2'], ['2', '2']]
```

HTML markup provides an specific element for lists

```
<ul>
 <li>Esto</li>
 <li>Lo otro</li>
 <li>Lo de más allá</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks. And then for the second part of the question about arrays?

Comment: thanks, with the list-comprehension you can sort of do it, but even so, from the `xpath(...)` you get a list -- `[<element>, <element]` in lxml. So this is to suggest that you can build whatever data-level nesting you want, but you'd need to do so in programming with some knowledge of the structure, right? For example, in the above way, you could have a list-of-list-of-list-of... etc. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: @David542 XML needs an external languaje to parse its structure into objects and yes that language needs to know the structure. So, its not tied to an specific languaje like json is. [lxml.objectify](https://lxml.de/objectify.html) can be used to deserialize xml into python objects. Same with java to parse json, java needs to know the structure.